# Do functionals agree almost everywhere if they agree except on the real-analytic functions?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $C^\infty(M)$ be the set of smooth functions on some manifold $M$, and suppose we have a pair of functionals

$$S_1,S_2:C^\infty(M)\to \mathbb{R}$$

which agree except on the subspace of real-analytic functions. Can we then say that "$S_1=S_2$ almost everywhere"?

Comment: "Almost everywhere" usually refers to a subset of measure zero when there is some natural measure on the space. Do you have one in mind for $C^\infty(M)$? There are other ways to express that subsets are "thin" in some sense without using a measure, e.g. if they are [first Baire category](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FirstCategory.html). Which one to use depends on the purpose, what do you want to use your "almost everywhere" for?

Comment: In my case, $M=S^1$, so I guess I really meant to ask this question with respect to the Wiener measure. Is the answer known in this case?

Comment: As I recall, Wiener measure is supported on continuous nowhere differentiable functions, so the entire $C^\infty(M)$ has measure $0$.

Comment: Haha that answers my question then - thanks!